# How can we define $\partial x_{i_r}^p(X_p^r)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X_r^s:M\to T_r^s(M)$ is a section. Let $P\subseteq M$ be an open set and $X_1,\ldots,X_s\in\mathcal T(P)$ and $X^1,\ldots,X^r\in\mathcal T^*(P)$ where $\mathcal T(P)$ and $\mathcal T^*(P)$ are the sets of local smooth sections on $TP$(tangent bundle) and $T^*P$(cotangent bundle), respectively.  I want to show that the function $X_r^s(X_1,\ldots,X_s,X^1,\ldots,X^r):P\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$X_r^s(X_1,\ldots,X_s,X^1,\ldots,X^r)(p)=X_r^s(p)(X_1^p,\ldots,X_s^p,X^1_p,\ldots,X^r_p)$$ 
is smooth if and only if section's component functions are smooth.

$$
\begin{align*}
RHS
&=C_{j_1\ldots j_s}^{i_1\ldots i_r}(p)dx_p^{j_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes dx_p^{j_s}\otimes\partial x_{i_1}^p\otimes\ldots\otimes\partial x_{i_r}^p(X_1^p,\ldots,X_s^p,X^1_p,\ldots,X^r_p)\\
&=C_{j_1\ldots j_s}^{i_1\ldots i_r}(p)(dx_p^{j_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes dx_p^{j_s})(X_1^p,\ldots,X_s^p)(\partial x_{i_1}^p\otimes\ldots\otimes\partial x_{i_r}^p)(X^1_p,\ldots,X^r_p)\\
&=C_{j_1\ldots j_s}^{i_1\ldots i_r}(p)dx_p^{j_1}(X_1^p)\cdots dx_p^{j_s}(X_s^p)\partial x_{i_1}^p(X_p^1)\cdots\partial x_{i_r}^p(X_p^r)\\
&=C_{j_1\ldots j_s}^{i_1\ldots i_r}(p)X_1^p(x^{j_1})\cdots X_s^p(x^{j_s})\color{blue}{\partial x_{i_1}^p(X_p^1)\cdots\partial x_{i_r}^p(X_p^r)}
\end{align*}
$$

**Main Question:** In the last line we have terms like $\partial x_{i_r}^p(X_p^r)$ and $\partial x_i^p(f)$ for $f\in C^\infty(p)$ is defined as $$D_i(f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))$$ 
Since $X^r\in\mathcal T^*(P)$, so $X^r$ is from $P\to T^*P$ and so $X_p^r$ is from $T_pP\to\mathbb R$ and so $X_p^r\notin C^\infty(p)$. Hence $\partial x_{i_r}^p(X_p^r)$ doesn't mean. What is wrong? Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried fixing a basis and dual basis for $T_pM$ and writing it in terms of that?

Comment: No, also I don't know what do you say!

Comment: you have that $X_1^p=x^1_{h_i}(p)\partial x_p^{h_i}$ and the $x^1_{h_i}$ are smooth functions and $dx_p^s(\partial x^p_t)=\delta_s^t$ and so on. Similarly for the $X^r$. Then you get that $\partial x^p_{i_r}(X^r_p)$ you open it up and you only need to understand what $\partial x^p_{s}(f (p)dx_p^t)$ is. Then coordinate smooth implies the whole is smooth just follows by product and sum of smooth things is smooth. The other direction follows by choosing your $X_i,X^j$ correctly. (I hope I did not mess the indices)

Comment: Do you say that $X_p^r\in C^\infty(p)$??

Comment: So $X^r$ is a smooth section of the cotangent bundle which means that in local coordinates you can write it as $\sum_i f_i(x) dx_i$ with $f_i$ smooth functions on the local chart. Smooth at a point means smooth in a neighbourhood (it is an open condition).

Comment: If you are taking $C^\infty(p)$ to be smooth functions at $p\in M$ and $x:U\subset M\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ we are talking about the same thing

Comment: In my lecture note, if $f\in C^\infty(p)$ then $\partial x_i^p(f)$ is defined as $D_i(f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))$. Now how do you define $\partial x_i^p(X_p^r)$, when $X_p^r\notin C^\infty(p)$?? Unfortunately I don't know what do you say!

Comment: @user302007: Part of the issue may be that you write "$X^{i} \in \mathcal{T}^{*}M$" instead of "$X^{i}$ is a local section of $\mathcal{T}^{*}M$". As Spotty explains, a local section can be written as a linear combination (with smooth functions as coefficients) of coordinate $1$-forms $dx^{j}$; the local coordinate functions $x^{j}$ are the local smooth functions $f$ you seek.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang What is difference between them? If $P$ is an open set and $X^i\in\mathcal T^*(P)$, then $X_p^r\in C^\infty(p)$?

Comment: (Note: It appears you're using $P$ to denote an open set and $p$ to denote a point, which is asking for trouble.) The phrase "$X^{i} \in \mathcal{T}^{*}P$" means what it says: $X^{i}$ is _one element_ of the cotangent bundle. By contrast, "$X^{i}$ is a local section..." means $X^{i}:P \to \mathcal{T}^{*}P$ is a section of the bundle projection, a local object that can be differentiated.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang In my question $\mathcal T^*(P)$ is the set of local smooth sections, so if
$X^i\in\mathcal T^*(P)$, then $X^i:P\to T^*P$ where $T^*P$ is local cotangent bundle, so $X_p^r\in T^*_pP$, that is $X_p^r$ is from $T_pP\to\mathbb R$. Now how $X_p^r\in C^\infty(p)$? I am not right?

Answer (score 1):

I will write the full proof for $X^1_1$ in your notation (just to not get cray with indices). So we have that locally:
$$ X_1^1(p)=\sum_{i,j} C^i_j(p) dx^j_p\otimes \partial x_i^p$$

Assume the $C^i_j$ are smooth functions. Pick $X,\alpha$ smooth sections of $TM,T^*M$ respectively. Which locally we can write as $X=\sum_i x_i\partial x_i$ and $\alpha=\sum_i f_idx_i$, so $x_i,f_i$ are smooth functions as well. Then:
$$ X_1^1(X,\alpha)(p)=\sum_{i,j} C^i_j(p)dx^j_p(\sum_hx_h(p)\partial x_h^p)\partial x_i^p(\sum_kf_k(p)dx^k_p)$$
now $dx_p^j(x_h(p)\partial x_h^p)=x_h\delta_{jh}$ and $\partial x_i^p(f_k(p)dx^k_p)=f_k(p) \partial x_i^p(x_k)=f_k(p)\delta_{ji}$ so the previous just becomes:
$$\sum_{ij}C^i_j(p)x_j(p)f_i(p)$$
which is a sum and product of smooth functions and therefore smooth.

Now for the reverse direction we want to show that each $C^s_t$ is smooth if $X^1_1$ is. From the previous expression it suffices to pick $X=\partial x_t$ and $\alpha=dx_s$.